# How To Generate IIF File(QuickBook File) From Datagridview or Datatable in C# or Vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable, quickbooks

Thanks in Advance :

How To Generate `IIF File(QuickBook File)` From `Datagridview or Datatable` in C# or Vb.net

I want To Generate IIF File From DataTable.

I tried this:

This Only Generates Data into tab delimeter

```
Public Shared Sub Write(dt As DataTable, filePath As String)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = Nothing
    sw = New StreamWriter(filePath, False)
    For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 2
        sw.Write(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName + " ")
    Next
    sw.Write(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
    sw.WriteLine()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim array As Object() = row.ItemArray
        For i = 0 To array.Length - 2
            sw.Write(array(i) + " ")
        Next
        sw.Write(array(i).ToString())
        sw.WriteLine()
    Next
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

But I want to Integerate Qb Employee So,pls provide Employee tab delimeter.

**I got This Output**

```
Full Name Start Date/Time Hours Mileage ConvertedDate
"ALLEN  SERINA " 11/17/2016 7:09AM CST 7.433333333333334  11/17/2016   12:00:00      AM
"ARMSTRONG   VANESSA " 11/17/2016 11:14PM CST 8.205274722222223  11/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
"BATTLE  BRANDON" 11/17/2016 6:08AM CST 8.133333333333333  11/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
"BEAL  PATRICIA" 11/17/2016 10:00AM CST 8.5  11/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
"BENNETT  AUIRIEL" 11/17/2016 3:06PM CST 7.574134722222222  11/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
"BRATCHER  SHEMEKA" 11/17/2016 4:27PM CST 6.150830555555555  11/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

**Please Give IIF Coding For Entering This Hour To QB Employee TimeEntry.**

Comment: `I want` is not a appropriate question on SO. Show your code and what you have tried. Then we can try to help you.

Comment: "Please Give IIF Coding For Entering This Hour To QB Employee TimeEntry." Please deposit my hourly rate into my bank account to receive code.